# How to vertically stack (and wrap) a list of block elements with css

Tags: html, css, layout

I have a ul / li list of which the **li** elements should stack vertically, *and wrap* after a certain number (either nth child or preferably parent height), like this:

```
1  4
2  5
3  6
```

How could this be done? (preferably without fixed pixel size and absolute positioning)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is column-count property.
Wrap the ul by a div with a class:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
  </ul>
</div>
.wrapper{
    column-count: 2;
    column-gap: 20px;//for spacing between
}
```

Comment: Thanks! The problem with this is that the sub items are wrapping in the column as well. Is there a way tell it to not wrap mid-li, first go to the closing li tag, then wrap?

Comment: i don't believe this solution would work for your case , i think you will need to use some javascript but if you post your html and the needed output i might be able to help

Comment: I think i figured it based on your guidance, Ill add it in an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out using `break-inside: avoid;`.

[Here is a Codepen](https://codepen.io/petergus/pen/ZePROz)

and here is the code

HTML

```
 <ul class="parent-menu">
  <li class="parent-menu-item">
  <a href="#">Parent item 1hey!</a>
    <ul class="child-menu">
      <li class="child-menu-item child-item-1">
      <a href="#">Child item 1</a>
        <ul class="grandchild-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Grandchild item 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Grandchild item 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Grandchild item 3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Grandchild item 4</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Grandchild item 5</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Grandchild item 6</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Grandchild item 7</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Grandchild item 8</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Grandchild item 9</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="child-menu-item child-item-2">
      <a href="#">Child item 2</a>
      <li class="child-menu-item child-item-3">
      <a href="#">Child item 3</a>                    
      <li class="child-menu-item child-item-4">
      <a href="#">Child item 4</a>
        <ul class="grandchild-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Grandchild item 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Grandchild item 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Grandchild item 3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Grandchild item 4</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Grandchild item 5</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Grandchild item 6</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Grandchild item 7</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Grandchild item 8</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Grandchild item 9</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="child-menu-item child-item-5">
      <a href="#">Child item 5</a>
        <ul class="grandchild-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Grandchild item 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Grandchild item 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Grandchild item 3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Grandchild item 4</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Grandchild item 5</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Grandchild item 6</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Grandchild item 7</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Grandchild item 8</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Grandchild item 9</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
```

And the cross browser css (as usual, see note about IE at the end)

```
.child-menu {
  -moz-column-count: 3; 
  -webkit-column-count: 3; 
  column-count: 3; 
  -moz-column-gap: 40px; 
  -webkit-column-gap: 40px; 
  column-gap: 40px; 
}
.child-menu-item {
  -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
  page-break-inside: avoid;
  break-inside: avoid;
}
```

To make this work on IE 9 and below, follow [this guide](https://pterkildsen.com/2012/12/08/css3-columns-in-internet-explorer-7-8-and-9/) and use the javascript in the code pen. Note: both javascript and CSS must be externally linked as far I can see.

Your result should look like this:

[image: CSS columns]

Special thanks to [Fadi Abo Msalam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5462970/fadi-abo-msalam) for his original answer here pointing me in the right direction!!